# Run systemd script in chroot from outside the chroot?

Tags: systemd, chroot

Is it possible to run a SystemD service with a different root? For example if I use `debootstrap` to install a parallel distro, and inside that distro is a systemd service I would like to run, is there a way to configure systemd in the host to do it?

I see `WorkingDirectory` in the script currently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SystemD supports this through `RootDirectory`,](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html)

> `RootDirectory=` Takes a directory path relative to the host's root directory (i.e. the root of the system running the service manager). Sets the root directory for executed processes, with the `chroot(2)` system call. If this is used, it must be ensured that the process binary and all its auxiliary files are available in the `chroot()` jail. Note that setting this parameter might result in additional dependencies to be added to the unit (see above).
>
> The `MountAPIVFS=` and `PrivateUsers=` settings are particularly useful in conjunction with `RootDirectory=`.

[`APIVFS`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html), is probably the most useful,

> Takes a boolean argument. If on, a private mount namespace for the unit's processes is created and the API file systems `/proc`, `/sys`, and `/dev` are mounted inside of it, unless they are already mounted